# Angular 2 - the simplest ngFor does not work

Tags: angular

I just found out something incredibly weird

I worte like a thousand of ngFor, and for some reason this one is not working

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div *ngFor="let array of wtf">
        test {{ wtf.name_fr }}
      </div>

    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  array=[{"name_fr":"test"}];
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

I've done a plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/SufVLD7cmPqxwSUd66v6?p=preview

I'd be really happy to know the why of this oddity

thanks

Comment: well your array is called `array` yet you are using `wtf`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <div *ngFor="let array of wtf">
```

should be

```
  <div *ngFor="let wtf of array">
```

[**Plunker exmple**](https://plnkr.co/edit/k6BxkqfWtlky6SwryLmb?p=preview)

Comment: Be prepared to encounter more such "moments" in your jurney with Angular. SO is here to watch your back ;-)